Sending Object as custom parameter in the custom GA4 event
Is it possible to pass Object in the custom parameter of the event? (Web Container in Tag Manager)
Right now in the Tagging Server I receive something like [Object object] instead of a proper JSON object. I don't really need to see that in the GA UI, I just want to pass it together with all the event data to the server.
Thanks!
I already checked documentation and Stackoverflow. Either the problem is not answered or it's not covered (documentation)
